# How to make the textarea label display correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive

I created a responsive form which changes to two columns when the screen size is resized. It mostly works the way I want it to.

However the label for textarea keeps showing incorrectly. I want it to display on a new line, but it keeps showing in the area of radio buttons.

There is also an issue with radio buttons where both can be selected at the same time. I have been trying to figure out what I did wrong but I can't find a solution.

[Here is my code on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6zhb3ek2/)

```css
/* CSS */

.myForm {
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.myForm h2,
.myForm p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.myForm h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.myForm p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.myForm label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

form input {
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.label,
.radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

input[type="radio"],
input.radio {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -8px;
  right: 5px;
}

.msg textarea {
  width: 96%;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}

form button {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /*Left form column*/
  .left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
  }
  /*Right form column*/
  .right {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
  }
  .label,
  .radio input[type="radio"] {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<form class="myForm">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="fields">
    <label class="left">First Name
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <label class="right">Last Name
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <label class="left">text
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <label class="right">text
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <label class="left">text
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <label class="right">text
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <label class="left">text
              <input type="text" name="other"></label>
    <div class="radio right">
      <label>Some text</label><br>
      <label class="label">
                <input type="radio" name="phone" value="phone">Phone</label>
      <label class="label close">
                  <input type="radio" name="email" value="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="msg">
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: For select one radio button you have to give same `name` for their attributes.

Comment: Oh! Of course, how did I miss that, thank you!

Comment: Your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zhb3ek2/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help:

```
.msg{
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I can't believe how easy that was, and yet I kept struggling. Thanks!

Comment: @daydreamer you probably want to learn how to use something like flex rather than using floats - with css3, you shouldn't be abusing floats for layout anymore

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the two problems you describe:

1. Your radio buttons need to have the same `name` field to be in the same group. If you set `name="contact"` for both, then they'll no longer be selectable at the same time.
2. You should remove `float: left;` from your CSS rules for `.radio input[type="radio"]`. This is taking precedence over the `display: block;` of the `.msg` `div` and causing them to be displayed on the same line.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for clarification on the second point.